# How to format date in VisualForce page with html table

Tags: visualforce

How can I format a date field from a query do that it does not cause a break as a new table row? Below is a table and the respective code.

[image]

```
<apex:actionRegion >
<apex:outputPanel layout="block" styleClass="header1" >
<apex:pageBlockSection columns="1" id="section2aa" title="Submission Summary Information" showHeader="true" >
<html>
<body>   
<br></br>
<table> 
<tr class="alldatatables">
<th> Contracts </th>
<th> Key Contact </th>
<th> Effective Date </th>
<th> N/R </th>
<th> Type </th>
<th> Coverage </th>
<th> Subject Prem </th>
<th> QS Part of % </th>
<th> Cession Limit </th>
<th> Treaty Limit </th>
<th> Event Limit </th>
<th> Att Type </th>
<th> LAE Type </th>
<th> ECO% </th>
<th> XPL% </th>
<th> Req Brok% </th>
<th> Req Reinstatements </th>

</tr>
<apex:repeat value="{!submissionList}" var="s" >
<tr class="alldatatables"> 
<td>{!s.SPD_REF_PS__c}</td> 
<td>{!s.Key_Broker_Contact_LU_PS__c}</td>
<td>
<apex:outputText value="{0,date,MM/dd/yy}"> <apex:param value="{!s.Est_CERT_Incept_Date_PS__c}"></apex:param> </apex:outputText>
</td>
<td>{!s.Submission_New_Renew_PS__c}</td> 
<td>{!s.Submission_Type_PS__c}</td>
<td>{!s.Coverage_PS__c}</td>
<td>{!s.Subject_Premium__c}</td>
<td>{!s.QUOTA_SHARE_PART_OF__c}</td>
<td>{!s.PRO_RATA_LIMIT__c}</td>
<td>{!s.Limit__c}</td>
<td>{!s.Event_Limit__c}</td>
<td>{!s.Attachment_Type__c}</td>
<td>{!s.RSO_LAE_TYPE__c}</td>
<td>{!s.RSO_ECO_PCNT__c}</td>
<td>{!s.RSO_XPL_PCNT__c}</td>
<td>{!s.BROKERAGE_PCT__c}</td>
<td>{!"--"}</td>
</tr> 
</apex:repeat>
</table> 
</body>
</html>

</apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:outputPanel>
</apex:actionRegion>
```

Comment: Try adding `layout="none"` to your `<apex:outputText>` tag.

Comment: @AdrianLarson layout="none" is not a parm for outputText. I did add layout="none" to the outputPanel but that did not change anything.